# How to keep the same request for two pages?

Tags: flutter

I have homepage with multiple listItem each item send a request to a server to get the latest update for the specific item (building tracking packages app) so for example you have 10 packages when you enter the app it will send 10 request to the server to get the updated location for them , what i am looking is when the user click in the item itself if the request didn't finish receiving data from the server it will keep that current request even it's in the detail page of that package . so it won't cancel the request and send another one in the detail page if the first request is still active . i hope i am making sense in this question .

I am using Dio for the request

Comment: I don't know what you want, because I don't view question.

Comment: Please check the question guidelines to improve your question and receive help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Captivity my question is how to can keep the request when  navigating to another page and the show the result in the new page you are in

Answer (score 0):

I am getting your point you want when the first request in progress I don't want to send a new request to at this time. you need to do few things when you are doing a request the first time then set a flag true until you do not get response and use the same flag check on your detail page before API call next time.